# Converting Numpy ndarray to a list

Tags: list, numpy, multidimensional-array

This is the result I get:

```
a=[array([[ 0.05019716]]), array([[ 0.04085874]])]
```

I would like to create such a list:

```
list_numbers=[ 0.05019716, 0.04085874]
```

Any advice will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way

```
In [9]: np.array(a).ravel().tolist()
Out[9]: [0.05019716, 0.04085874]
```

Convert `a`, list, to NumPy array, then flatten it to array elements using `ravel()`, then convert to list using `tolist()`.

However, for this specific case, you could also use list comprehensions

```
In [10]: [x[0][0] for x in a]   # or x[0, 0]
Out[10]: [0.050197159999999998, 0.040858739999999998]
```