# How can I convert numpy ndarray to a list of tuples efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy

Here's the numpy.ndarray I've got:

`a=[[[ 0.01, 0.02 ]], [[ 0.03, 0.04 ]]]`

and I want it to convert to

`a = [(0.01, 0.02), (0.03, 0.04)]`

Currently I just use the following `for` loop but I'm not sure whether it's efficient enough:

```
b = []
for point in a:
   b.append((point[0][0], point[0][1]))
print(b)
```

I've found somewhat [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450901/converting-numpy-ndarray-to-a-list) but there're no tuples so a suggested `ravel().tolist()` approach didn't work for me here.

Comment: Why are you using a lsit?

Comment: PS. you cannot append 2 elements in a list

Comment: @DirtyBit I'm sorry, just edited the question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
# initial declaration
>>> a = np.array([[[ 0.01, 0.02 ]], [[ 0.03, 0.04 ]]])
>>> a
array([[[0.01, 0.02]],
       [[0.03, 0.04]]])

# check the shape
>>> a.shape
(2L, 1L, 2L)

# use resize() to change the shape (remove the 1L middle layer)
>>> a.resize((2, 2))
>>> a
array([[0.01, 0.02],
       [0.03, 0.04]])

# faster than a list comprehension (for large arrays)
# because numpy's backend is written in C

# if you need a vanilla Python list of tuples:
>>> list(map(tuple, a))
[(0.01, 0.02), (0.03, 0.04)]

# alternative one-liner:
>>> list(map(tuple, a.reshape((2, 2))))
...
```

Comment: Any reason you put the `2L` there? In Python 3 all integers are long integers, so I would propose to remove those `L`s as to not confuse new Python programmers into thinking this is "good style" or even "required".

Comment: @NOhs I did so for consistency but I see your point, will edit thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use list comprehension, they are faster than for loops

```
a = np.array([[[ 0.01, 0.02 ]], [[ 0.03, 0.04 ]]])
print([(i[0][0], i[0][1]) for i in a])  # [(0.01, 0.02), (0.03, 0.04)]
```

alternatively:

```
print([tuple(l[0]) for l in a])  # [(0.01, 0.02), (0.03, 0.04)]
```

Comment: Not bad either! ;)

Comment: Shorter alternative: `tuple(i[0])`.

Comment: @DirtyBit you shouldn't alter his solution without his consent, because there was nothing wrong with it. My comment was just for future reference.